# Swift : Button not responding to tap

Tags: ios, swift

Hey so I'm new to coding and I placed a button on my View Controller (Drag and drop). The button is not responding to touch or anything and appears 'static.' I'm tired and exhausted. Someone help? Thank you so much!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMadeToday: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Cents: UILabel!
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var hourlyWage : CGFloat = CGFloat (hourlyPrice)
    var timeTo1 : CGFloat = 0
    var time : Float = 0
    var earnt : CGFloat = 0
    var madeToday : CGFloat = 0

    @IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    func tick() {
     earnt = CGFloat (time)/timeTo1
     lbl1.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", earnt) as String


        if (earnt >= 1) {
            time = 0
            madeToday++
            lblMadeToday.text = madeToday.description
        }
        time++
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timeTo1 = CGFloat (360000)/hourlyWage;

        println("view Loaded :)")
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"doYourStuff", name:
            UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }


    func doYourStuff(){
        var nowHour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: NSDate())
        var nowMinute = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: NSDate())
        var nowSecond = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: NSDate())

        var time1 = (nowHour - globalHour) * 60
        var time2 = (nowMinute - globalMinute)
        var time3 : CGFloat  = (CGFloat(nowSecond)-CGFloat(globalSecond))/60
        var timeInMinutesGone : CGFloat = CGFloat(time1) + CGFloat(time2) + CGFloat(time3)
        println (timeInMinutesGone)
        madeToday = (timeInMinutesGone / 60) * (CGFloat(hourlyWage))
        var ef : Int = Int(madeToday)
        lblMadeToday.text = String(ef)
    }

    @IBAction func btnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("hello")
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: IBAction func btnPress,  IBAction func btnClick. Why do you have two ibactions? Are they linked to the same UIButton?

Comment: After deleting all IBAction Funcs, I rerun the application and the button still does not highlight :/ Is there something preventing action on the view controller? or is there an overload of processing being caused by the timer? :/

Comment: Try putting a print statement in the IBAction function.  See if it's in the console on click.

Comment: Linked this to the button and nothing gets printed to the console :/ SO confused! Thank you for your help so far
    @IBAction func btnTester(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("test")
    }  T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NSTimer is being executed in the UI thread every 0.01 seconds. This could be detrimental for your app. It's likely that if you execute NSTimer in a background thread, your button will work as expected.

One way to add your NSTimer to background could be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) How do I do this in the background thread? Thank you so much! I am new to this so please be as simple as possible :)

Comment: @LouisJordan, did it work this for you?

Comment: Omg yes thank you so much agy! :) You were so helpful - I need to find an online course on this stuff haha I look on udemy

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks